# Does our body affect our personality?

Tags: behavioural-neuroscience

Some may argue that our body is independent from our personality, and whether you are taller, shorter, black, white, etc does not have any influence on how your mind works and interprets the world. Are there any shreds of evidence to prove this argument wrong?

- Could it be said that how our body is composed, its aspect, and how
  it reacts to its environment would affect our personality and the way
  of acting in the world or those are isolated and our personality does
  not react to how our body is made?
- For instance, two twins with different personalities, could it be said that their body affected their personality in different manners, and having had different body both of them, they would have had two other personalities, different between them as well?

Is there any aspect of psychology studying this?